# PHP functions to execute a script in background?

Tags: php, function, background, cross-platform, execution

I have bunch of PHP Scripts that require execution on press of a button in an HTML web page. I have browsed through various PHP functions which could do that, however I am confused as to which of these functions listed on PHP Manual will work best in my situation.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

In total there are following four buttons on a single web page linking to their respective scripts.

1. Archive    ==>   archive.php        // takes few minutes.
2. Download   ==>   download.php       // takes 3 to 6 hours.
3. Format     ==>   format.php         // takes few seconds.
4. Update     ==>   update.php         // takes few minutes

Also, which of these functions are cross platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using 'system', and it works correctly.

```
$last_line = system('ls', $retval);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "the last line of the output: ". $last_line;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Return value: ".$retval;
```

Just replace 'ls' with your command, like "php text.php".

Good luck.

Comment: sure will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Abhishek, I believe you are looking at running PHP scripts when someone clicks on a button on you HTML page. To run a PHP script, you need to simply call the URL. The only pre-requisite is that you need to be running a PHP server. You should look at [Beginning PHP development - programming stack recommendation and web site resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847515/beginning-php-development-programming-stack-recommendation-and-web-site-resour) to know how to run PHP scripts.

Comment: I have finished with coding the script, I can run it by calling it from browser 'localhost/update.php', however require to know how can that be achieved on a click of a button, meaning the script should run in background.

The reason behind it, closing the browser would terminate the script, and the script can take anywhere from 3 to 6 hours, and i don't want to keep the browser open for that long.
Any solutions?